# Best Tools for helping debug an Interop issues

Tags: .net, c++, windows, comexception

One of our customers is getting an interop issue, there is nothing in the stack trace that is worth noting, just ComException with an InterOp issue.

I've tried Process Monitor and Dependency Walker, but nothing seems to pop up.

It is C++ Managed running on .net 1.1.

Any helps with any tools would be a life saver!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [managed debugging assistants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d21c150d%28VS.80%29.aspx) in Visual Studio are designed for precisely this sort of thing and will catch things like GC releasing an COM pointer that's already gone (ie. native side reference counting problems).

Other than that the best tool I've found is a lot of patience and using WinDBG with [SOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx)

Comment: +1, you're gonna have to man up and use the big-kids debugger for this one